# How to remove space when concatenating data from different rows into one column using xml?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

I am trying to combine data from different rows into one column, and this is working with just one minor problem.

```
declare @RitID int = 16

select ...,

       ( select distinct
                ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(r2.LotNr)), LTRIM(RTRIM(r.LotNr))) + '+' as 'data()'
         from   tblExtraBestemming eb2   
           inner join tblRit r2 on eb2.RitID = r2.RitID
         where  eb2.BestemmingID = eb.BestemmingID
         and    eb2.BestemmingTypeID = eb.BestemmingTypeID
         and    (  (eb.CombinedChildExtraBestemmingID is null and eb2.RitID = @RitID)
                   or
                   (eb.CombinedChildExtraBestemmingID is not null and eb2.RitID in (select r4.RitID from tblRit r4 where r4.MasterRitID = @RitID) )
                )
         for XML PATH('')
       ) as LotNr
from tblExtraBestemming eb
where ...
```

this returns the correct data for the column LotNr, like this

```
GTT18196
GTT18197
GTT18198+ GTT18199
```

Now my only problem is the space after the `+` sign in the third row from the result, how can I get rid of this ?

I expect this result

```
GTT18196
GTT18197
GTT18198+GTT18199
```

PS, actually there is also a  `+` at the end of each row, but that is removed by the client. I thought I better mentions this already.

EDIT
I checked the data, there are no spaces at the end or the beginning of the data

EDIT
Query updated as suggested by @Larnu

**EDIT**
if I check the data in the table, this is the result

```
select '/' + r.LotNr + '/' from tblRit r where r.RitID in (50798, 50799)

COLUMN1 
------- 
/GTT18198/  
/GTT18199/
```

So it appears to me there are no characters before or after the data

Comment: Use LTRIM and RTRIM in your query

Comment: Well it doesn't look like the column is coming from using XML Path, which makes me think it's in your data. Could it be as simple as `RTRIM(isnull(r2.LotNr, r.LotNr))` in your select ?

Comment: @Bridge I checked, there are no spaces before or after the values in the table

Comment: Could it be a different control character, other than space? If so, `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` won't remove it. Perhaps try replacing CHAR(10) and/or CHAR(13), the two character that make up new lines.

Comment: @Bridge See the latest edit in my answer

Comment: `(eb.CombinedChildExtraBestemmingID is not null and eb2.RitID in (select r4.RitID from tblRit r4 where r4.MasterRitID = @RitID)` -> `(eb.CombinedChildExtraBestemmingID is not null and r2.MasterRitID = @RitID)` ?

Comment: `if I check the data in the table` - you have isnull with 2 aliases. Did you check both? What is `r.` alias here by the way? One more thing: you have `DISTINCT` whereas _third row_ contains two similar values: `GTT18198+ GTT18198`

Comment: @IvanStarostin the column `LotNr` can come from 2 different sources. Only one can be filled, so the `isnull` is to find out which source to use.

Comment: ...i can understand that. And the second source is...? Again, did you check both sources?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes I did, the other source is null as expected

Comment: Anyway this is not the full code - for two values it would return `val+val+` but it does not have posterior '+', so _the other_ code may be modifying the output.

Comment: @IvanStarostin the posterior + is removed by the client, that is mentioned in the question. I omited the posterior + in the question to simplify the example

Comment: Why rely on the client and not use the `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` method for creating delimited data?

Comment: `DISTINCT` still does not think those values are equal. No idea why you want `GTT18198+GTT18198` after `DISTINCT`. It must be single `GTT18198` in this case.

Comment: @IvanStarostin oops there was an error in the question, it should be GTT18198+GTT18199. But anyway, the problem is solved now, see the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `AS 'data()'` from your query (it is not required in the above case).

And if trailing `+` is a problem, move it to the beginning and use `STUFF` function to chop off the first character from the result.